# 'Object property set inside decorator function doesn't persist as expected.'

Tags: javascript, function, object, nested-function, object-properties

I've only been learning to use JavaScript for 4 months, so please let me know if there is something obvious I am missing.

In this problem, I am writing 2 functions,

- One is the inner (non-critical) work function. It just adds 2 numbers.
- The second is the decorator function which needs to store the arguments of work function into the function object properties of work itself, as work.calls = [ [num1, num2], [etc, etc] ];
- According to the setup of the problem, after being defined, the functions need to be called like this:

```
work = spy(work);
work(1, 2);
work.calls; // => [1, 2]
```

I followed the section 'Custom Properties' of this article [Function Object](https://javascript.info/function-object). So I'd expect the function object property (work.calls) to persist in the work object after I invoked spy(work).

When I ran the code under the debugger, I got a strange result.

- The work.calls is defined inside the block of the spy function
- The work.calls becomes undefined at work(1, 2)

My attempted solution looks like this:

```
function work(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + num2;
}

function spy(target) {
  target.calls = [];
  //set work.calls, work.calls is currently existing in debugger.
  
  function wrap(x, y) {
   
    target.calls.push([x, y]);
    
    return target(x, y);
  };
  
  
  return wrap
}

work = spy(work);

work(1, 2);
work.calls; // => now undefined in the debugger!
```

Another solution I found suggest to change target.calls to wrap.calls, and it fixed the problem. So does this mean function object properties are NOT persistent unless created from within their own body?

```
function spy(target) {
  
  
  function wrap(x, y) {
   
    wrap.calls.push([x, y]);
    //using wrap instead of target allows work.calls to be persistent 
    
    return target(x, y);
  };
  
  wrap.calls = [];
  
  return wrap
}

work = spy(work);

work(1, 2);

work.calls; // => [1, 2] all good in work.calls... but why?
```

I can't figure out why setting wrap.calls allows the property to persist. Aren't objects always persistent on the global scale?

Thanks so much for your patience. I just hope someone can help me make sense of this.

Comment: the returned `wrap` function is not the original `work` function - so, the global `work` function is now the `wrap` function, and therefore does not have the `calls` property, since that exists on the original `work` function - try `test = work` before `work = spy(work)` you'll see that `test` will have the `calls` property you create on the original `work`

Comment: "*does this mean function object properties are NOT persistent unless created from within their own body?*" - no. `wrap.calls = [];` does not create the property from inside of the body of `wrap` either.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I was mixed up by what each function was returning. The ``` spy(work) ``` call was actually returning the nested wrap(x, y) function. And when I set ``` work = spy(work) ```, I was overwriting the original global work function object with the new 'nested wrap' function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to avoid `work = spy(work);` at first. Instead write

const spiedWork = spy(work);
…

Then compare what happens when calling `work(1,2)` and what happens when calling `spiedWork(1,2)`. Also compare `spiedWork.calls` with `work.calls`. Once you have this figured out (and that `spiedWork !== work`), you'll understand what happened in the original code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think the problem is I didn't understand that spy(work) was returning wrap(x, y), I thought the entire chain of nested functions was being returned. 

As a side question, is it possible to invoke the entire ```spy( work(1, 2) )``` nested functions in one line? Or would I have to always put the ```let someVar = spy(work)``` in order to start using the nested ```wrap(x, y)``` function?

I would upvote you but my rep is still too low 

Comment: You can in theory write `spy(work)(1,2)`, but then you have no variable with the wrapped function on which you can access `.calls`. If you insist on one line, `(spiedWork = spy(work))(1, 2)` is also possible, but I wouldn't advise it either.

Comment: Thanks again for your quick responses. No, I don't insist on it, I am just learning and just wanted to know if it was possible in theory. I appreciate the help :)